# leur taille... n'y est pas étrangère

Tags: y

> Les virus ont été découverts tardivement, à la fin du xixe s. ; leur taille, quelques dixièmes de micromètres pour les plus gros, n'y est pas étrangère. Même Edward Jenner, qui a mis au point le vaccin contre la variole, ou Louis Pasteur, qui a découvert le vaccin contre la rage, n'ont pas pressenti leur existence.

Comment comprenez-vous ce "n'y est pas étrangère"? Expliquez-le moi, s'il vous plaît, soit en anglais, soit en français. Bien que je possède un DALF C2, je suis dérouté ici.

En voici la source: https://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/divers/virus/101864

Answer (score 5):

Il faut comprendre *étranger* dans le sens référencé [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9tranger#Adjectif) en numéro 3:
Qui n’est pas partie prenante

*Ne pas être étranger à quelque chose* signifie donc "contribuer à quelque chose, y être partie prenante". Le pronom "y" peut alors remplacer ce *à quelque chose*.

Ici, le "y" remplace l'idée que les virus ont été découverts tardivement. On peut paraphraser par "leur taille n'est pas étrangère au fait que les virus ont été découverts tardivement".

Donc, cela signifie que leur petite taille est une des raisons pour lesquelles ils ont été découverts tardivement.